# Enqueued Stylesheet Version Number Not Being Appended

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css

I have an issue with the child theme stylesheet being browser cached, and I need to dequeue/reregister, then re-enqueue with a timestamp for the version number. The dequeue then re-enqueue is working fine, but no matter what I try there isn't a version number being appended. I've tried to set the version parameter of `wp_enqueue_style()` to both true, and a string. No matter what there isn't a version number added as a query string to the stylesheet link href. My full code snippet is below.

```
function custom_dequeue_enqueue_child_styles() {

    wp_dequeue_style('mk-style');
    wp_deregister_style('mk-style');

    $cacheBuster = filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('jupiter-child-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), $cacheBuster, 'all');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_dequeue_enqueue_child_styles', 999999999);
```

Comment: Nobody can put a possible answer on this?

Comment: Your code is pretty much the same as what I use to include a version number. My guess is something else is affecting it - do you have a caching plugin, or CSS concatenating plugin, or something like that? If you disable all plugins does it then show the version number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the code does indeed work, and the reason the version number was being stripped out was due to a buried theme option that by default removes all version numbers from all JS and CSS files.

This is in the Jupiter WordPress theme by Artbees, and the theme option is in Theme Options > Speed Optimization > Query Strings from static Files. By default its set to "off" and that removes version numbers. Setting it to "On" appends version numbers as query string parameters. This is a very dumb option to be enabled by default, but now we know.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I was working on a theme I inherited from someone else, and wasn't aware that soil (https://roots.io/plugins/soil/) was being used to disable script versioning.